translate3d virtualization on scroll?
I saw some websites using CSS translate3d to virtualize list and table by manipulating viewport, such as AirTable. I googled translate3d virtualized and translate3d virtualized react, but I didn't find useful websites. How is it called this approach? Could you provide some useful websites about this?
Also, what are the pros and cons of this approach compared to the approach of traditional approach such as react-window?
